# kdb/q What kind of Join would I need for this scenario?

Tags: join, kdb

I have two tables like this:

participants: each person in the race, along with their score and the name of race they ran in

| Name | Score | Race |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Ann | 66 | 8a |
| Bob | 20 | 8a |
| Ann | 73 | 7d |
| Bob | 25 | 7d |

races: the name of each race, and whether it was included in the final tallying score

| Race | included |
| --- | --- |
| 8a | 0 |
| 7d | 1 |

At the end, I want to calculate the scores for each participant for only those races that are included in the final tallying score.

What kind of join would I need to create a combined table that includes the "included" column?

| Name | Score | Race | included |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ann | 66 | 8a | 0 |
| Bob | 20 | 8a | 0 |
| Ann | 73 | 7d | 1 |
| Bob | 25 | 7d | 1 |

Thanks for the help.

Comment: your FROM clause would look something like: `FROM participants INNER JOIN races ON participant.Race = races.Race`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The response above was close but the where clause was in the wrong place:

```
q)select sum Score where included by Name from(participants lj`Race xkey races)
```

| Name | Score |
| --- | --- |
| Ann | 73 |
| Bob | 25 |

Another way to get the results is by removing the parentheses and adding "= 1" for clarification:

```
q)select sum Score where = 1 included by Name from participants lj`Race xkey races
```

Comment: Your first example is not the intended usage of where in a select clause. If the included field are longs then you need to perform some comparison to return a list of booleans:
"select Score by Name from (participants lj`Race xkey races)where included=1"

Comment: Your 2nd example is just incorrect and doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

You need a left join and then a select by clause on the joined table.

```
q)select sum Score by Name from(participants lj`Race xkey races)where included
Name| Score
----| -----
Ann | 73
Bob | 25
```

Comment: I have a quick question, I've been trying this out and for some reason it's throwing me an error:

Comment: participants:([]Name:ABAB; Score: 6 2 7 3; Race: 8a8a7d7d)

Comment: races: ([] Race:8a7d; included: 0 1)

Comment: q) Select sum Score by Name from (participants lj`Race xkey races) where included

Comment: 'included [6] Select sum Score by Name from (participants lj `Race xkey races) where included

Comment: Do you know why this might be throwing this error for the included field? Sorry the comments don't allow new lines so I had to post as different comments

Comment: Actually never mind, I just found out the 'where' clause was in the wrong spot: Select sum where included Score by Name from (participants lj `Race xkey races)

Comment: Your included field are longs - where in a select statement expects a boolean list. You are also seeing an error because your statement reads `Select...` rather than `select...`